# Java Code to get output of running program

Tags: java, linux

I want to run the following command from a java program:

```
socat -x -u /dev/ttyFTDI0,raw,echo=0,crnl /dev/ttyFTDI1,raw,echo=0,crnl
```

This program is supposed to run for an indefinite time while outputting hex strings like this:

> b4  03 03 92  00 01 3f  c6  b4 03 10  03 00 01  6a af

My current testing code is:

```
public void testOutput() {
    try {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("socat");
        command.add("-x");
        command.add("-u");
        command.add("/dev/ttyFTDI0,raw,echo=0,crnl");
        command.add("/dev/ttyFTDI1,raw,echo=0,crnl");

        ProcessBuilder proBui = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process process = proBui.start();
        //process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            String temp = r.readLine();
            if (temp != null && !temp.isEmpty()) {
                //do something with data
                System.out.print(temp);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

While this code works for commands that finish after a given time, commands like the one given or `watch ls` won't work.

Comment: in your example, the output is on one line. maybe that "r.readLine()" never respond because it's waiting for a end-of-line char ? what's your error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the `socat` documentation](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html), the `-x` option

> Writes the transferred data not only to their target streams, but also to stderr.

You are reading from `process.getInputStream()` which is connected to the native process stdout - to get stderr you should read `process.getErrorStream()` instead.

Comment: Why would they put that into stderr?!? I changed the code to fetch the ErrorStream and it works. Thank you very much @IanRoberts